# Validar input en angularJS $error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Cómo puedo validar para que el `botón` no me permita cambiar la contraseña hasta que no sean iguales?, algo con `$error` o `ng-message`.

Quiero que cuando le de cambiar contraseña valide que si hay algo en los input y que sean iguales, de lo contrario no haga nada.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.changePassword = function() {
        if ($scope.newPassword == $scope.confirmNewPassword) {
            console.log("contraseña son correctas");
        }else {
            console.log("contraseña no coinciden, vuelva a intentar");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <label>Nueva contrasena:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="newPassword" placeholder="Nueva contrasena" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <label>Repetir Contrasena:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="confirmNewPassword" placeholder="Repetir contrasena" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <button type="button" ng-click="changePassword()">Cambiar contrasena</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona correctamente. Que es lo que te falla?

Comment: @Einer algo como un ng-disable al botón cambiar contraseña, pero no lo quería hacer con el ng-disable :D, es decir que se debe ingresar algo a los input para poder que ejecute el botón cambiar contraseña.

Comment: Osea, si no hay nada escrito en los inputs que el button este deshabilitado?

Comment: @Einer que el botón valide que debe haber algo escrito para poder ejecutar, no necesariamente que este desahabilitado por que ya lo hice con ng-disable, solo quería saber otras opciones de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es validar que tengan datos, entonces utiliza la propiedad `.length` que te da el total de caracteres de un `string`. Si ambos son igual a 0, entonces es muestras el error:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.confirmNewPassword = "";
    $scope.newPassword = "";

    $scope.changePassword = function() {
        if($scope.newPassword.length == 0 || $scope.confirmNewPassword.length == 0)
        {
           console.log("Los campos contraseñas son requeridos");
        }
        else if ($scope.newPassword == $scope.confirmNewPassword) {
            console.log("contraseña son correctas");
        }else {
            console.log("contraseña no coinciden, vuelva a intentar");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <label>Nueva contrasena:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="newPassword" placeholder="Nueva contrasena" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <label>Repetir Contrasena:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="confirmNewPassword" placeholder="Repetir contrasena" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <button type="button" ng-click="changePassword()">Cambiar contrasena</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias amigo algo asi buscaba :)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que leas esta guía para hacer exactamente lo que necesitas.
Aquí utilizan una directiva para controlar los match de 2 inputs y lo utilizan con **$error**.
Eso si, también te recomiendo que no la llames ngMatch como hacen ahí. Cámbiale el nombre ya que el prefijo ng podría causar conflicto con las directivas de angularjs

[AngularJS Password Match form validation](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/10/05/angularjs-password-match-form-validation/)